# Here Maps api: how to get current center showing on the map (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, here-api, here-maps-rest

Is there a way to retrieve the coordinates of the center showing on the map?

The user can navigate freely on the map, so the center constantly changes.

How can I retrieve the current center?

Answer (score 2):

In JS, `map.getCenter()` .
Check javascript developer’s guide at developer.here.com

Answer (score 0):

```
      center_latLng = map.getCenter();

      center_lat = center_latLng.lat;

      center_long = center_latLng.lng;

      center_zoom = map.getZoom();
```

api doc is at

https://developer.here.com/documentation/maps/3.1.37.0/api_reference/H.Map.html#getZoom